# Leetcode claims that exception is not handled which I handled

Tags: c#, exception, dynamic-programming

I am trying to solve Dynamic Programming questions from leetcode. Started from the easiest ones. Fibonacci. I handled the `IndexOutOfRangeException` and tried my code with different values on my computer. But when I submit it, leetcode says:

```
Runtime Error
Unhandled exception. System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
At Solution.Fib(Int32 n)
At __Driver__.Main(String[] args)
```

Here is the code:

```
public class Solution
{
    public int Fib(int n)
    {
        int[] table = new int[n + 1];

        // Seed the trivial answer.
        table[1] = 1;

        // Iterate and fill further positions based on current values.
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                table[i + 2] = table[i] + table[i + 1];
            }
            catch (IndexOutOfRangeException ex)
            {
                // Out of array bounds.
            }
        }

        return table[n];
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if `n` is -1?

Comment: Or even what happens if n is zero?  hint:  `table = new int[1]` then `table[1] = 1` then various fire trucks and emergency services arrive as things catch fire.

Comment: @DavidL n can not be -1. It is not appropriate for calculating Fibonacci.

Comment: Instead of handling `IndexOutOfRangeException` better avoid it by choosing the correct loop limits.

Comment: @Baran that's your assumption. And what I'm telling you is that you didn't account for that as a possible entry, unless the leetcode _specifically states_ that it cannot be a non-negative number.

Comment: If n = 0, then `table[1] = 1` will error.

Comment: @KlausGütter it is not efficient that check with an if which will get into only at the end of the array. I mean inside if will be executed only once but it will check in every iteration. Not efficient thats why I used try catch

Comment: You are right I will handle cases for n is negative or 0

Comment: I mean if you replace `i < n` by `i < n - 1` then the case where you get the exception from `table[i + 2]` is avoided.

Comment: @KlausGütter you are absolutely right. Thanks I fixed it

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the people at the comments, I noticed I forgot handle the cases with n<1.

```
public class Solution
{
    public int Fib(int n)
    {
        if (n < 1)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        int[] table = new int[n + 1];

        // Seed the trivial answer.
        table[1] = 1;

        // Iterate and fill further positions based on current values.
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                table[i + 2] = table[i] + table[i + 1];
            }
            catch (IndexOutOfRangeException ex)
            {
                // Out of array bounds.
            }
        }

        return table[n];
    }
}
```

Thanks to the Klaus from the comments `n - 1` instead of `n` will also avoid the `IndexOutOfRangeException` exception so I don't have to use try catch anymore.

```
for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++){
    table[i + 2] = table[i] + table[i + 1];
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Your return could be triggering that because it is outside the try/catch.  Based on your logic, I don't see how you would actually get IndexOutOfRangeException there, but it could be a code quality scanner that isn't happy.
Another possibility is that because your logic will always get IndexOutOfRangeException within the try/catch, the system is upset because you didn't actually 'handle' the catch, just ignored it.

Comment: The exception IS handled, by definition. Swallowed, yes, but it is handled. And as I and others in the comments have pointed out, there are code paths that can throw an `IndexOutOfRangeException` that is NOT part of the try/catch.